# convert array of object to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have an array object like below:

```js
[
    {
        first: "A",
        second: "B"
    },
    {
        first: "C",
        second: "D"
    },
]
```

and I want to convert to an array like this:

```js
[
    [
        "A",
        "B"
    ],
    [
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
]
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the values.

```js
const
    data = [{ first: "A", second: "B" }, { first: "C", second: "D" }],
    result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```